# Inner joining UDF on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table valued function that does a complex query and returns a table (UDF1), and then I have another table that has a bunch of rows that can be used to reduce the output from this UDF.

Is it possible to join these two and pass columns from the table as arguments to the UDF ?

like,

```
SELECT * 
FROM UDF1 (TBL1.Column1, TBL1.Column2)
INNER JOIN TBL1
           ON (TBL1.Column3 = UDF1.Col3)
```

Comment: -2. Maybe need to use alias on the UDF.

Comment: just to clarify, i did try and i know the error i will get, i am just trying to communicate the intention, to see if someone knows some other way to achieve this ...

Comment: Then please show the error you "will" get!

Comment: well it would say tbl1.column1 couldnt be bound ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) syntax here.

For reasonable performance, the UDF should be an inline one rather than a multistatement one if at all possible.